# Did I handle this review task correctly?

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to ask how this specific review task should have been handled. The answer itself is obviously not an answer but the way the new user posted it makes it hard to tell at a glance what would be wrong with it without going to the answer itself.

For starters I am referencing this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29048775/3915817

The person says "I tried but not working" followed by posting the text of another answer almost verbatim. The user obviously did not know how to put this information in a proper block quote which is why when I looked at it I almost thought they were trying to steal the answer as their own.

In the end what I did was edit the answer to be properly formatted. The only thing I did differently was to flag it for moderator attention over simply marking it not an answer. I felt the extra context would be necessary to identify it for deletion over just what someone would see in a review queue, especially without the edit applied.

I especially feel this was likely the better solution when looking at how others reviewed the same question, seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7343297, marking it as no action needed. I would still like the opinion of others though so I know what to do in the future though. Should I have used the needs moderator attention flag or just trusted that the not an answer flag would have been properly handled?

Comment: I would have flagged NAA and added a comment to the LQP reviewers, linking to the specific answer it attempts to reply to.

Comment: I flagged it as NAA 1 or 2 hours ago, before coming here, and without seeing it in a review queue. Seemed very obvious what it was. Well, that was after your edit. Looking at the edit history, I most likely wouldn't have recognized it without the copied part actually being formatted as a quote.